# Where to store large HTTP data in Vue JS app with Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm building a basic twitter like app with Vue and Python. I'm not sure what best practices are in terms of how to best structure tables and where to store data returned from an API.

I have a table for users, tweets, and follower/followed. As of right now, the login makes a call to get user information and then another HTTP call is made after a successful login to retrieve all of the user tweets.

My tables are currently set up like this:
**Users:** id, username, password, first_name, last_name
**Tweets:** id, tweet_text, created_on, author_id(user.id)
**Follower/Followed:** id, follower_id, followed_id

I currently make the call for tweets and store all of the data in an array in Vuex(state management) but doesn't seem ideal? I'm only showing tweet_text but now getting to reflecting firstname and lastname so do I make another http call and store all users locally?

Everything I've come across online regarding statemanagement and HTTP calls are for simple small requests. In this case I'm not sure what best practices are for the amount of times to make HTTP requests and whether to store data locally or not and how much of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make fetches to pull all of a table and store it as in object. You can also pull all of the data from the tables and sort it with an algorithm on the frontend and place it in the state. It sounds more like an SQL question than a Vue/Vuex question.

You can use an inner join to get all tweets and their users, sort that on the frontend in whatever format you like and then persist it in the state. You basically just have to decide if you want to organize it in the backend via SQL or in the frontend via JavaScript.